# How to reuse a function or class in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

This is my class `TimesheetListApiV2` there are lots of such kind of classes.

```
@valid_accesstoken_check
class TimesheetListApiV2(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        try:
            accesstoken=AccessToken.objects.get(
                        token=self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').replace('Bearer ', '')
                    )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response (
                {
                    "status" : False,
                    "error" : "Wrong Access Token",
                    "error_message":"You have provided wrong access token.",
                }
            )
```

Now in all my classes this piece of code is there.

```
try:
    accesstoken=AccessToken.objects.get(
                token=self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').replace('Bearer ', '')
            )
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return Response (
        {
            "status" : False,
            "error" : "Wrong Access Token",
            "error_message":"You have provided wrong access token.",
        }
    )
```

I want to write a function or class where to reuse that code instead of writing it. But it should be workable even `request` should be pass. Even in future i am going to add more such code which should be reused.

I tried to make this decorators.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken

def valid_accesstoken_check(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            accesstoken=AccessToken.objects.get(
                        token=self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').replace('Bearer ', '')
                    )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response (
                {
                    "status" : False,
                    "error" : "Wrong Access Token",
                    "error_message":"You have provided wrong access token.",
                }
            )
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

But it is giving error

```
path('timesheet/list', views.TimesheetListApiV2.as_view(), name='api_v2_timesheet_list'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Comment: Looks like you need a decorator?

Comment: How can i create a decorator.

Comment: @E.Serra i tried to make decorator but it is giving error

Comment: You can create a Mixin for that

Comment: @ruddra i tried to create mixin also but it is not working. In mixin i have put get method. How can i create mixin for that because mixin and decorator is new topic for me

Comment: composition is usually better than inheritance, usually. Decorators in classes are very tricky, but they are worth the effort, all you want to say is a(fun): try:.... fun() except: whatever and then decorate this type of functions with that. Decorators are a very very powerful tool, worth the effort

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator should apply to the `get` method, not the class itself:

```
class TimesheetListApiV2(APIView):
    @valid_accesstoken_check
    def get(self, request):
    ...
```